# Which ternary operator to use?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, python-2.x

I've been wondering whether should I write

```
lambda pixel: (0,0,0) if pixel == (0,0,0) else (255,255,255),
```

or

```
lambda pixel: pixel if pixel == (0,0,0) else (255,255,255),
```

This may be a silly question, but I want to get better at forming questions.

And I wonder if there may be any caveats I don't know of.

I personally consider latter to be more readable.

Comment: Use whichever one you prefer. It is entirely a matter of choice.

Comment: It may not be obvious that this is a subjective, pure-opinion question (without knowing, it makes sense to worry that one of them might be bad…), but as it happens, it is. So, the question will probably get closed, but don't take that personally.

Comment: Note that the two aren't exactly equivalent-- if `pixel` isn't a tuple but a custom object which can compare equal to `(0,0,0)`, then the first one will return `(0,0,0)` despite that and the second will return the custom object.

Comment: @SteveJessop: DSM's point isn't just about identity here; it makes sense to write some code that duck-types tuples and `Pixel` instances the same way, even though other code (e.g., some C image library) that you use in the same program doesn't…

Comment: It's more of a context-dependent question, as you pointed out in your answer, @abarnert. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @abarnert: I deleted the comment since my point was just that there exist potential semantic differences. DSM got in while I was writing my comment and gave one example, and I don't see a need for more in this case. But if the questioner wants more then I suppose a new version of the question is in order that avoids the dreaded words "should I write" :-)

Comment: Personally I prefer `lambda pixel: (255,255,255) if sum(pixel) else (0,0,0)` Advantages 1) you are always getting a 3 member tuple, 2) it is more clear (IMHO)

Comment: @dawg: why do you prefer `sum(pixel)` to `any(pixel)`? I'm assuming that pixel values are non-negative numbers, so there aren't any values like `-1` or `None` that would make either one of them not equivalent to all-elements-equal-to-zero. To me `any` reads clearer.

Comment: @SteveJessop: `why do you prefer sum(pixel) to any(pixel)` Brain stoppage only. `any` is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely the latter.

If you use the former, and someone edits just one of the literal values, now it's broken:

```
lambda pixel: (0,0,0) if pixel == (0,0,8) else (255,255,255),
```

I introduced a bug in the above.  I edited the tuple used in the condition, but didn't edit the first tuple.  This is hard to spot by casual inspection.

Consider this:

```
big_long_expression if something == big_long_expression else whatever
```

The reader has to mentally evaluate `big_long_expression` each time, and compare whether they are actually the same or not.  If you instead use the latter form, now it's clear: you either return the expression unchanged, or in the else case you return something else.

It's the same reason I prefer the `+=` operator:

```
my_class.a.b[i+3] = my_class.a.b[i+3] + 2
```

compare with:

```
my_class.a.b[i+3] += 2
```

Both do the same thing, but the second one is so much easier to understand.

I always prefer the syntax that expresses your intentions more clearly.  I think your second format makes it most clear: check a condition, and when it's true leave the value alone, else return a special value.

EDIT: in comments directly under the question, @DSM made an excellent point.  The first expression also has a subtle property: it always returns a tuple, even when the expression being compared wasn't a tuple.  As long as `pixel` is any class that can be compared to a tuple, either expression will work.  But if you want your lambda to consistently return a tuple from either case of the ternary, then the first form is preferable.

Here are two rewrites of your code, for your consideration.

The first:

```
ORIGIN = (0, 0, 0)
lambda pixel: ORIGIN if pixel == ORIGIN else (255,255,255),
```

Now at least there is a single point to edit to change the origin.  This is the way I'd recommend if you do want to always return a tuple.

The second:

```
lambda pixel: pixel if pixel == (0, 0, 0) else type(pixel)((255, 255, 255))
```

This gets the type of `pixel`, then calls that type to construct a new object.  This assumes that the `pixel` is of a class that is not only comparable to a tuple, but that if you pass a tuple to the class it will use that to build a new instance of the class based on the tuple.

An example of this in use:

```
f = lambda pixel: pixel if pixel == (0, 0, 0) else type(pixel)((255, 255, 255))

class T(tuple):
    """
    Make a class that acts exactly like a tuple.
    """
    pass

x = T((1,2,3))
assert type(x) == T
assert type(x) == type(f(x))

x = (1, 2, 3)
assert type(x) == tuple
assert type(x) == type(f(x))
```

Comment: @StoryTeller I did before the edits made it a decent answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When I first started posting to StackOverflow, I would write answers similar in length to the above all in one edit, then post.  And upon posting, I would find that someone had typed two sentences with the core idea, posted it, and been rated +5 and accepted as the answer while I was writing the long one.  And then I would get no votes as my answer was now redundant!  I found this to be frustrating and demotivating.  Thus, I now tend to post a short answer and then update it with multiple edits.  Perhaps you don't approve of this strategy?  What should I do instead?

Comment: @steveha Your strategy is fine. Your first post was too short though. It just said, "definitely the latter" without any justification. So you do run the risk of picking up downvotes for that. There's no problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this definitely isn't a syntax issue; it's just a matter of style. (In a more complex expression, it would be a different story… but then in a more complex expression, often you should have been breaking it up into simpler expressions anyway…)

Personally, I think they're both perfectly readable. The first one emphasizes that `(0, 0, 0)` is the default value more clearly, while the second one emphasizes the purpose of what you're returning more clearly, and it repeats a simpler thing (`pixel` instead of `(0, 0, 0)`). But these are both such trivial benefits that I don't think it matters that much.

Comment: And who downvoted this!?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Some people believe in down voting any answers to obvious-bad-needs-to-be-deleted questions should be downvoted, and I suspect someone thought this question qualifies as such. (I obviously disagree on both counts, or I wouldn't have written an answer, but neither one is beyond comprehensibility.)

Comment: That's an ugly use of the voting privilege... I dare say the downvoter knows this, or they would have identified themselves